# Comparing line by line

Tags: arrays, awk

I have an array of IDs given as follow.

```
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_959,ZTE_GENERIC_959,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_959,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-120,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_959,ZTE_GENERIC_959,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_959,-100,568,0,0,0,0,0,-25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_988,ZTE_GENERIC_988,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_988,-9,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_1010,ZTE_GENERIC_1010,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_1010,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-141,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_959,ZTE_GENERIC_959,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_959,0,0,0,0,0,0,-79,-67,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_959,ZTE_GENERIC_959,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_959,0,0,0,0,0,0,-474,146,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_1219,ZTE_GENERIC_1219,HYBRIDE,ZTE_GENERIC_1219,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-210,137,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_1010,ZTE_GENERIC_1010,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_1010,-127.5,85,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_988,ZTE_GENERIC_988,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_988,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_1081,ZTE_GENERIC_1081,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_1081,-126.4,71,0,0,0,0,-63.2,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20140201,ZTE_GENERIC_959,ZTE_GENERIC_2_ZTE_GENERIC_959,PREPAID,ZTE_GENERIC_959,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-142,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I'm looking for a awk script to find duplicate in this list. The script i'm using consider only the first column so the output is wrong. I want at least 3 or 4 columns to be compared so the result will be correct

Comment: here is my awk script
`awk -v Thvar="$THREADIDARR" 
BEGIN{  command=cut -d "," -f 1 }
{ CURTHREADID=getline | command
for(index in Thvar){
 if(CURTHREADID == Thvar[index]){print;break;}
}}' $INPUTFILE     `

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1)

```
awk 'a[$0]++' File
```

This will show all duplicate lines.

2)

```
awk '!a[$0]++' File
```

This will remove all duplicate lines if that's what u want.
This will check the entire line...

We are using a counter array `a` with the `entire line` as index and increasing count by one the first time. Next time, the condition will be false, since count corresponding to that line `will not be zero` and hence `!a[$0]` will fail and the duplicate line will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , Your question is not clear.
please deside upon either three column or 4 column comparision.
If complete line needs to be comapred , then you already have the solution from A M D but with a little change . add a flag for field separator `-F,`

If 3 column:

```
awk -F, '!a[$1$2$3]' File
```

If 4 column:

```
awk -F, '!a[$1$2$3$4]' File
```